# React-hook-form: unable to successfully implement MUI Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a wrapper around the MUI Select component, and while I've found some solutions that *seem* to be really close to working. They simply don't and I'm not sure why.

I've attached a picture of the error plus the related code. Any ideas how to get around this?

[source template I'm trying to use](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-mui-select-tqe89?file=/src/index.js:775-1097)

##### error message

[image]

##### my controller

```js
<FormControl>
  <Controller
    name="sourceLanguage"
    rules={{ required: 'this is required' }}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={sourceLanguage}
    as={
      <Select>
        <MenuItem value="">None</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="fr">French</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="es">Spanish</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    }
  />
</FormControl>
```

##### useForm hook

```js
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<dynamicFormState>({});
```

##### related state

```js
export interface dynamicFormState {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  contentId: string;
  sourceURL: string;
  sourceLanguage: string;
  targetLanguage: string;
  author?: IYoutubeAuthor;
  content?: IYoutubeContent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're mixing RHF's v6 and v7. Your `<Controller />` component uses v6 syntax with the `as` prop, while you're probably using v7 as a dependency in your project (therefore the TS error noting that `as` is not a property of `<Controller />`). Write your `<Controller />` using the `render` prop instead of `as` should fix the error.

```
<FormControl>
  <Controller
    name="sourceLanguage"
    rules={{ required: 'this is required' }}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={sourceLanguage}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <Select {...field}>
        <MenuItem value="">None</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="fr">French</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="es">Spanish</MenuItem>
      </Select>  
    )}
  />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank you! that was actually what I came across as well. Seems to be working mostly correctly now. However ... now all of my MenuItems are appearing horizontally stacked and not vertically stacked. Solve one bug, find another :)

Comment: It’s hard to tell not knowing your exact html and styles, but I would guess it has possibly something to do with how you structure your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just use this package below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-react-hook-form-plus

```
import { HookSelect, useHookForm } from 'mui-react-hook-form-plus ';

const Component = () => {
    const {registerState, handleSubmit} = useHookForm({
        defaultValues: { sex: '' },
    });
    
    const onSubmit = (data: typeof defaultValues) => {
        // will run if it is valid
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <HookSelect 
             {...registerState('sex')}
             items={[
                { label: 'MALE', value: 'male' },
                { label: 'FEMALE', value: 'female' },
                { label: 'OTHERS', value: 'others' },       
            ]}
            />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

### [See Demo](https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/hookselect--hookselect)